# Select rows based on a condition in numpy/python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I generate a random matrix of normal distribution and size 4x4; then I have to select rows whose sum is greater than 0.

When I write the code using 2D indexing, the output doesn't seem right:

```
a = np.random.randn(4, 4)
a[a[:, 0] > 0]
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Please specify expected output

Comment: rows whose sum is greater than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) combined with [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randn(4, 4)
indices = np.where(np.sum(a, axis=1) > 0)
print(a[indices])  # rows with sum > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
a = np.random.randn(4, 4)
print(a)
```

which in this case gives:

```
[[-0.73576686 -0.34940161 -0.87025271 -0.61287421]
 [ 1.2738813  -0.3855836  -1.55570664  0.43841268]
 [-1.63614248  1.4127681   0.37276815 -0.35188628]
 [ 0.18570751 -0.31197874 -2.05487768 -0.05619158]]
```

and then apply the condition:

```py
a[np.sum(a, axis = 0)>0,:]
```

which here results in:

```
[[ 1.2738813 , -0.3855836 , -1.55570664,  0.43841268]]
```

Edit:
For a bit of explanation, `np.sum(a, axis = 0)>0` creates a 1D Boolean mask. We then apply this to the rows of `a` using index slicing as `a[np.sum(a, axis = 0)>0,:]`.